# 3v3 VLogic for DG212

Tags: logic-level, analog-switch

I am curious if anyone knows if a Vishay DG212 works with VLogic being powered by 3v3?

The only test conditions the datasheet speaks of are where VL is being powered by 5v.

Here is the datasheet:
http://www.vishay.com/docs/70040/70040.pdf

The simplified schematic makes it seem like sending 3v3 to VL should be no problem since it is the logic high reference for a MOSFET H Bridge (I think?), but I wanted to ask the community if anyone has any experience using these chips in real life using lower logic levels than specified in the datasheet. I don't have an opportunity to test this out before I build a PCB, so I was hoping to get some real world experience from elsewhere.

V+ and V- in my situation would be powered by 12v rails (just an FYI)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DG202-DG212.pdf
>
> Compared to the original manufacturer’s products, Maxim’s DG202/DG212
>   consume very little power, making them better suited for portable
>   applications. Maxim has also eliminated the need for the third logic
>   power supply (VL) that is required for the operation of the original
>   manufacturer’s DG212 without sacrificing compatibility.

I don't have any experience with the chip. I suspect that the VL voltage may bias the transistor performance, thus implies the rest of the system. I also searched from other manufacture datasheet state that the Absolute Maximum Ratings of `VL to Ground` is `-0.3V to 25V`. You may need to test it yourself for your specific application to see any effects.

But if you need an answer fast, I think you should use the Maxim version instead to avoid **uncertainty**.

Comment: You should expect an imbalance in propagation delays.

Comment: The maxim chip will definitely work (I could just cut the 3v3 line if it causes problems). I may do that if it the Vishay version does not work with 3v3, but I have word from a friend that the vishay version does in fact work with 3v3.

Comment: @cosmikwolf Yes, it doesn't require VL so that you don't have to think about 3.3 or 5V anymore as I already quoted above. It will work, but as analogsystemsrf said, there will be a performance trade-off. It depends on your specific applications and design requirements.

Comment: While it _might_ work and you friend says it will _probably_ work, I would never design the Vishay part into a 3.3V circuit unless the data sheet says it _will_ work. Sure the first few units might be fine but then you go to production and start getting failures. Never assume characteristics not explicity guaranteed in the datasheet. When in doubt, call the company.